# UK visa refused. My passport has this barcode

Tags: uk, passports, visa-refusals, applications, poland

What does this barcode mean? Is this a refusal stamp?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that barcode wasn't part of your passport all along? Based on the numbers at the top of your passport, it looks like it's simply your passport number, and many countries put such a barcode at the end of their passports. I'm not sure it has anything to do with your UK visa refusal.

Comment: There is no place on the Schengen application that asks for previous refusals, so not sure what you are referring to.

Comment: Yes Burhan it is the tracking number of my passport .

Comment: my question was when Poland embassy take my   biometric fingerprint scans can they see my refusal for and where else I have applied

Comment: You have two separate questions here, “What is this stamp?” and “Do I need to tell Poland about my refusal?” I would recommend editing this question to be just about the stamp and ask about the Poland visa separately.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your visa, this is stamped by NADRA (the issuing agency for Pakistani passports).

You'll note, its the same as the booklet number (printed on the bottom right of the photo page, after the tracking number) and is used for tracking of the passport when it is being produced.